# Verify CPU usage calculated by BP

Tags: block-producer, cpu

As far as I know, the value of CPU usage of the same tx can be different on every BP.

Is it possible for BP to overcharge CPU usage of my transaction?
If so, how do I (or other BPs) check if CPU usage was calculated right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered at **EOSIO/eos** repo [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5926):

> Theoretically they can, but this is unlikely to happen because this will make the network unhealthy and would not be any benefit to the BP.
>
> There's no way to check for this as CPU usage is subjective. so each BP has to trust the CPU usage in the transactions of the block produced by other BPs.